# Multiple Toggle IDs - Close One When Another Open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with lots of toggle boxes. When one closes I'd like another to open. Because of the layout of the design there are five hyperlinks in a row and then five hidden boxes below which toggle (so I've used unique ID's for the divs and buttons) - there's a total of about 40 of these rows so it's quite long - probably something more efficient available? However, now I'd like to close one, when another is toggled open. I've tried to find a solution but can't seem to. Here is my JQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$( "#button1" ).click(function() {
$( "#item1" ).slideToggle();
});
$( "#button2" ).click(function() {
$( "#item2" ).slideToggle();
});
$( "#button3" ).click(function() {
$( "#item3" ).slideToggle();
});
});
```

and here is my HTML:

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="onefifth"><a id="button1" href="#"><img src="assets/01.jpg"></a></div>
        <div class="onefifth"><a id="button2" href="#"><img src="assets/02.jpg"></a></div>
        <div class="onefifth"><a id="button3" href="#"><img src="assets/03.jpg"></a></div>
      </div>
      <div id="item1" style="display: none;">
            BOX CONTENT
        </div>
      <div id="item2" style="display: none;">
            BOX CONTENT 2
      </div>
      <div id="item3" style="display: none;">
            BOX CONTENT 3
      </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Quite new to JS and struggling a bit...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In your case specifically It would be better if you could provide a working JSFiddle with what you have. Also, StackOverflow has an [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One nice approach that will give you more control over the elements is avoid the use of hardcoded ID's to refer your buttons, instead use the class of the parent you already have; I suggest on your `<a>` elements use the `href` attribute to store which target you want to open.

To close the other elements you can `slideUp()` all `#item...` containers or use a flag like a `active` class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".onefifth").on('click','a',function() {
    var targ = $(this).attr('href');
    $('[id^="item"]').slideUp();
    $(targ).slideToggle();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="onefifth">
    <a href="#item1"><img src="assets/01.jpg"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="onefifth">
    <a href="#item2"><img src="assets/02.jpg"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="onefifth">
    <a href="#item3"><img src="assets/03.jpg"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="item1" style="display: none;">
  BOX CONTENT
</div>
<div id="item2" style="display: none;">
  BOX CONTENT 2
</div>
<div id="item3" style="display: none;">
  BOX CONTENT 3
</div>
```

---

#### Option 2

If you can be sure the order of your buttons and the order of your containers will match then you can simplify more this with the use of a common class on the containers no ID's.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".onefifth").on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.content').slideUp().eq($(this).parent().index()).slideDown();
  })
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="onefifth">
    <a href="#"><img src="assets/01.jpg"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="onefifth">
    <a href="#"><img src="assets/02.jpg"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="onefifth">
    <a href="#"><img src="assets/03.jpg"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  BOX CONTENT
</div>
<div class="content">
  BOX CONTENT 2
</div>
<div class="content">
  BOX CONTENT 3
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Legend :-D

Comment: Glad to help u @EdJohnson

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to all your divs likes this:

```
  <div class="contentBox" id="item1" style="display: none;">
        BOX CONTENT
    </div>
  <div class="contentBox" id="item2" style="display: none;">
        BOX CONTENT 2
  </div>
  <div class="contentBox" id="item3" style="display: none;">
        BOX CONTENT 3
  </div>
```

Then you can just just do a close on all of those before you open the new ones

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $( "#button1" ).click(function() {
      closeOpenContent();
      $( "#item1" ).slideToggle();
    });
    $( "#button2" ).click(function() {
      closeOpenContent();
      $( "#item2" ).slideToggle();
    });
    $( "#button3" ).click(function() {
      closeOpenContent();
      $( "#item3" ).slideToggle();
    });
});

function closeOpenContent(){
     $(".contentBox:visible").slideToggle();
}
```